# What are the differences between Constraint programming and Logic programming?

Tags: programming-languages, declarative, declarative-programming

I am aware that Constraint programming and Logic programming are sub-paradigms of Declarative programming. But I couldn't find a difference between them. What is the difference between them? Could you please provide some examples?